How to debug ignite::thin::cache::query::SqlFieldsQuery and ignite::thin::cache::CacheClient::Query exceptions in C++ Ignite client API
I am trying to run GridGain (same thing as Ignite) SQL Query as per https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/sql-api . While my code is very similar to the sample in the above documentation page it throws an exception.
Shortened version of my code:
using namespace ignite::thin;
using namespace ignite::thin::cache;

client = IgniteClient::Start(cfg_);
cache = client.GetOrCreateCache<std::string, GGainSerializer>("cache1");

query::SqlFieldsQuery query = query::SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT distinct typeName, typePfx, typeRunDate, typeId FROM cache1 ORDER BY typeName, typePfx, typeRunDate, typeId");
query::QueryFieldsCursor cursor = cache.Query(query);
while (cursor.HasNext())
{
    query::QueryFieldsRow row = cursor.GetNext();
    std::string name = row.GetNext<std::string>();
    std::string prefix = row.GetNext<std::string>();
    std::string runDate = row.GetNext<std::string>();
    int8_t type = row.GetNext<int8_t>();
}

Exception is thrown in line:
query::QueryFieldsCursor cursor = cache.Query(query);
Questions:

Does Ignite/GridGain C++ Thin client support SQL queries? Or I must use Thick client? I would prefer to avoid Thick client since my code will run on a grid where connection to GridGain cluster will be established every time a task starts executed and will be dropped when the task completes. The number of tasks is in multiple thousands. So I believe using Thick client which maintains a local cache is not advisable and will adversely affect GridGain servers and network traffic.
What type of exception is being thrown and how can I get an error message from that exception to understand the root cause? API documentation says nothing about it: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/cppdoc/classignite_1_1thin_1_1cache_1_1CacheClient.html#a38660ee6bc4f9c8e46bd46a4937a08f8:~:text=query%3A%3AQueryFieldsCursor-,ignite%3A%3Athin%3A%3Acache%3A%3ACacheClient%3C%20K%2C%20V%20%3E%3A%3AQuery,-(
How can I find out which SQL capabilities are supported by Ignite? Is 'distinct' supported?
Documentations https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/sql-api says: "SQL Fields Query can only be performed using fields that have been listed in "QueryEntity" been of the config!" I assume 'been' here should be 'bean' and refers to Java bean. "QueryEntity" class is not listed in the Ignite C++ class reference: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/cppdoc/index.html . So can someone from the Ignite team please explain what is meant here and give an example?

Thank you
